# Spark Dataframe - process 2 CSV files

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. Have a query tied to CSV file read.

I am trying to read 2 CSV files in 2 separate dataframes and 'Take' 5 rows from each. However, I am seeing only last dataframe action being printed. Am i missing something? Why first CSV dataframe action was not printed?

```
# Read first CSV

file_location1 = "/FileStore/tables/airports.csv"
file_type1 = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema1 = "true"
first_row_is_header1 = "false"
delimiter1 = ","

# Load File 1 
df1 = spark.read.format(file_type1) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema1) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header1) \
  .option("sep", delimiter1) \
  .load(file_location1)

**df1.take(5)**

# Read second CSV 

file_location2 = "/FileStore/tables/Report.csv"
file_type2 = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema2 = "true"
first_row_is_header2 = "true"
delimiter2 = ","

# Load File 2 
df2 = spark.read.format(file_type2) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema2) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header2) \
  .option("sep", delimiter2) \
  .load(file_location2)

**df2.take(5)**
```

**Output: only second dataframe output can be seen**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO7GO.png)

```
df1:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
_c0:integer
_c1:string
_c2:string
_c3:string
_c4:string
_c5:string
_c6:double
_c7:double
_c8:integer
_c9:string
_c10:string
_c11:string
_c12:string
_c13:string
df2:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame = [Parcel(s): string, Building Name: string ... 100 more fields]
Out[1]: [Row(Parcel(s)='0022/012', Building Name='580 NORTH POINT ST', Building Address='580 NORTH POINT ST', Postal Code=94133, Full.Address='POINT (-122.416746 37.806186)', Floor Area=24022, Property Type='Commercial', Property Type - Self Selected='Hotel', PIM Link='http://propertymap.sfplanning.org/?&search=0022/012', Year Built=1900, Energy Audit Due Date=datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 1, 0, 0), Energy Audit Status='Did Not Comply', Benchmark 2018 Status='Violation - Did Not Report', 2018 Reason for Exemption=None, Benchmark 2017 Status='Violation - Did Not Report', 2017 Reason for Exemption=None, Benchmark 2016 Status='Violation - Did Not Report', 2016 Reason for Exemption=None, Benchmark 2015 Status='Violation - Did Not Report', 2015 Reason for Exemption=None, Benchmark 2014 Status='Violation - Did Not Report', 2014 Reason for Exemption=None, Benchmark 2013 Status='Violation - Did Not Report', 2013 Reason for Exemption=None, Benchmark 2012 Status='Violation - Did Not Report', 2012 Reason for Exemption=None, Benchmark 2011 Status='Exempt', 2011 Reason for Exemption='SqFt Not Subject This Year', Benchmark 2010 Status='Exempt', 2010 Reason for Exemption='SqFt Not Subject This Year', 2018 ENERGY STAR Score=None, 2018 Site EUI (kBtu/ft2)=None, 2018 Source EUI (kBtu/ft2)=None, 2018 Percent Better than National Median Site EUI=None, 2018 Percent Better than National Median Source EUI=None, 2018 Total GHG Emissions (Metric Tons CO2e)=None, 2018 Total GHG Emissions Intensity (kgCO2e/ft2)=None, 2018 Weather Normalized Site EUI (kBtu/ft2)=None, 2018 Weather Normalized
```

Comment: Can you share complete code instead? Where did you try to print?

Comment: Hi @PiyushPatel, I have given complete code above. Not sure if you are looking for anything else. I printing output in Jupyter notebook itself, not to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it happening?

- The `take` operation does not print the result to your standard output
- Spark operations are lazy, so all the transformations are only evaluated once you ask for a final result (for example, print result to screen or save it to a file)
- In your last line Spark is guessing that you actually want to *see* the result, so it evaluates `df2` reading five lines from the file. On the other hand, `df1` is never evaluated and only the schema is known as it is inferred.

Try using [show](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=take#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show) instead, like `df1.show(n=5)`, it should trigger the evaluation of the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you @stjernaluiht for reverting. I replace `df1.take (5)` and `df2.take(5)` in above code with 'df1.show(n=5)' and 'df2.show(n=5)`. However, output remained similar. 5 rows from `df2` are printed. `df1` output not seen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's how Databricks was supposed to work. Every notebook environment actually does this. It displays only the last results. So, if you want to display results of both dataframes, probably you should write them in two different cells. You've written complete code in a single cell. It is not meant to be used that way. You write single line and verify that it's successful and then you add new lines. So, for try, you can add following in two separate cells and you will see results for both.

```py
# Read first CSV

file_location1 = "/FileStore/tables/airports.csv"
file_type1 = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema1 = "true"
first_row_is_header1 = "false"
delimiter1 = ","

# Load File 1 
df1 = spark.read.format(file_type1) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema1) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header1) \
  .option("sep", delimiter1) \
  .load(file_location1)

df1.take(5)
```

```py
# Read second CSV 

file_location2 = "/FileStore/tables/Report.csv"
file_type2 = "csv"

# CSV options
infer_schema2 = "true"
first_row_is_header2 = "true"
delimiter2 = ","

# Load File 2 
df2 = spark.read.format(file_type2) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema2) \
  .option("header", first_row_is_header2) \
  .option("sep", delimiter2) \
  .load(file_location2)

df2.take(5)
```

If you want to print it, you will have to use `print()` explicitly.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @piyushpatel. Appreciate your insight. It works when both files are read in separate cells as you mentioned. However, when I try to read both CSV files in one program using `spark-submit` from shell, output is similar to what notebook/Databricks environment shows. Action tied to only second file, be it `take()` or `show()` or `count()` is executed

Comment: I do not think it should happen. I don't have any idea on where you submit your spark code, but we do have in-house cluster and I have tried `count()` function, it always results for whatever you're trying to count. It's not good to count in production, but it does give results with aggregated yarn logs.

Comment: can you try creating 2 dataframes in a single program and use `count()` on both of them? Let me know if you can see both counts in output